# With Regular expression getting uri template parameter

Tags: regex, templates, uri

I need to get the parameters from my URI template with regular expression.

With my  regex `\{?([^{}?]*)\}`  from this URI template `www.blah.com{?id, name}/{bla}/kla/{hla}` I can get following parameter:

```
Match 1
1.  id, name
Match 2
1.  bla
Match 3
1.  hla
```

I need to separate between `Id` and `name`, so at the end, I will have 4 parameters (`id`, `name`, `bla`, `hla`).

Comment: So is there a query param in there?  What do you mean by {?id, name}?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `{?id, name}`, but based on the example you provided you could just use `\{?([^{},?]*)[\},]`. It'll split on the ending `}` or a comma. This will break the id and name into separate groups.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks it almost did! With the regex \{?([^{},?]*)[\},] I have 4 parameters, but I still have comma and curly brackets as following: 1. id, 2. name}  3. {bla}  4. {hla}.  So how to filter out the commas, and curly brackets to get only the values?